# ¿ Cómo agregar elementos dentro de un JTable en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, jtable

Estoy haciendo una Aplicacion con Java **(Uso el IDE Netbeans 8.0.2)** donde tengo un JInternalFrame  y un JDialog el cual obtengo datos en el JDialog, Hasta ahi me funciona perfectamente ahora lo que quiero hacer es desde el JDialog insertar la fila seleccionada en la tabla principal del JInternalFrame.

- Como podría hacer, en la misma tabla del JDialog si agrega los datos pero no en la principal.
- También quiero insertar elementos dentro del JTable como JTextField  como podría hacer también ?

Este es la tabla Principal que esta en el JInternalFrame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta el la Table de JDialog :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del botón **Seleccionar** que permite agregar los datos.

```html
private void btnSeleccionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        DefaultTableModel modelo;
        String tipo = txtIdTipoNew.getText();
        if (tipo.equals("1")) {
            String idDescrip = tblProducto.getValueAt(tblProducto.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString(); <!--**tblProducto** es el nombre de la tabla que se encuentra en el JDialog-->
            int cantidad = 1;
            String descripcion = tblProducto.getValueAt(tblProducto.getSelectedRow(), 8).toString(); 
            String medida = tblProducto.getValueAt(tblProducto.getSelectedRow(), 10).toString();
            String valCompra = tblProducto.getValueAt(tblProducto.getSelectedRow(), 11).toString();
            String igv = tblProducto.getValueAt(tblProducto.getSelectedRow(), 12).toString();
            String Subtotal = tblProducto.getValueAt(tblProducto.getSelectedRow(), 13).toString();
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) orden.tblOrden.getModel(); <!-- **orden.tblOrden.** es el nombre de la tabla principal-->
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"1",idDescrip,cantidad, medida,descripcion,valCompra, igv,Subtotal});
        } else {
            String idDescrip = tblProducto.getValueAt(tblProducto.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, idDescrip + "<= Tipo 2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "en la misma tabla del  JDialog si agrega los datos pero no en la principal."? Son dos tablas distintas. Lo que tienes que hacer es usar un código similar al que muestras pero con la tabla que quieres actualizar.

Comment: Bueno me refiero que tengo una tabla principal en un JInternalFrame y otra en un JDialog,  lo que quiero es agregar la fila seleccionada desde el JDialog a la principal  pulsando el boton seleccionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo que hice fue crea un boton llamado actualizar que me recargue los datos de la tabla 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el la opciones de Code cuztomizer le di public y static para poder ejecutarlo desde otra ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo en la ventana emergente en el botón de guardar al final agregue una linea que ejecutara este botón y listo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si no quiere que se vea el boton le puede hacer un `btn_miboton.setVisible(false)`
Obviamente la tabla debe estar alimentada de una base de datos